# Force linker / C compiler to include defined but unused inline functions?

Tags: gcc, linker, clang, compiler-flags, linker-flags

My project consists of one `.c` file and a math library in one `.h` file, with **all functions declared inline**. Not every function in the math library is used in the main program. These functions are not compiled into the executable.

However, some of the unused functions might still be useful in debugging, because gdb's `print` statement can evaluate arbitrary expressions. Is there a way to force `gcc` to include all defined functions, including `inline` functions, in the final executable, even if they are not used?

(I am not using any `-O` flags. This happens with both `clang` and `gcc`. A solution where I must introduce a separate linking step is fine.)

Comment: gcc shouldn't normally remove unused non-static functions. Are you sure it removes them? Please show your build command.

Comment: `gcc -std=c99 -Iinclude -g src/test.c` (warning flags not included)

Comment: (deleted comments - had false alarm thinking it might be a `clang`-only issue, but it happens in `gcc` too)

Comment: Not reproducible http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/399f28f982f7ce15

Comment: @n.m. declare the function `inline`

Comment: Um no. *You* don't declare the function inline, or declare it extern inline. Inline implies static in c. gcc **will** remove unused static funcions. Please use a [mcve] next rime.

Comment: Calm down. I mentioned that most of the functions were inline in my original question and now edited the title to reflect that after replying to your "not reproducible"

Comment: I'm sorry I must have missed this. It stillwould be easier to spot in the code.

Comment: You could add [`__attribute__((__used__))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) to the functions you want to keep. I do not know about a global flag, however.